# Reuse subscriber

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

In RxJava I have a `Subscriber` object wich I subscribe on a `Observable`. Later on (some time after `onComplete()` has been invoked) I create a new `Observable` and subscribe with the same `Subscriber` instance used before. However, that seems not work. Is a subscriber not reusable?

Example:

```
class Loader extends Subscriber<T> {

   public void load(){
       Observable.just("Foo").subscribe(this);
   }

   public void onComplete(){
     // update UI
   }

}
```

In my code I would like to instantiate a `Loader` once, and call `load()` multiple time, for instance after the user clicks on a refresh button ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot reuse `Subscriber`, because it implements `Subscription`, which has an `isUnsubscribed` field which, once set to `true`, will never become `false` again, so `Subscription` is not reusable.

`Observer`, on the other hand, does not contain any information about the subscription status, so you can reuse it. Each time you subscribe an `Observer` to an `Observable`, the RxJava implementation will wrap it inside a `new Subscriber` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Observable::concat` to create an Observable that emits the items from several Observables in sequence. Subscribe that.

Comment: I don't want to concat them ... The first observable is in no relation with the second observable ... They are independent. I just want to "reuse" the subscriber

Comment: But conceptually, you're saying "Subscriber, take these items; then, take those items".

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my example code is misleading. I changed my example to give you a better example.

Comment: You're using it wrong, methinks - why not simply `this.onNext(...)`? Or something with a more descriptive name?

Comment: But in general, is a `Subscriber` reusable?

Comment: I think that you mean `Observer`. And an `Observer` is reusable. But avoid to share it between subscription, otherwise you may deal with multithread issue in your `Observer`. You won't need `Subscriber` if it doesn't deal - by itselft - with unsubscription.