# Observable.from() does not work

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am learning RxJava in Android. I am following this tutorial [here](http://plavatvornica.com/rxjava-for-beginners/):

as shown in the code below, i have three observables and one subscriber. at run time, myObservable2 and myObservable2 are executed but not myObservable3.

to find out why myObservable3 s not executed, I commeted out myObservable2 and myObservable2 and ran only myObservable3 and then it ran normally.

why I can not run myObservable2 and myObservable2 and myObservable3 at the same time.

**code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

Observable myObservable1 = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {

    //this method cant be overriden
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext("first observer");
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
});

Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "I am done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNext: " + s);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //can use the same subscriber
    Observable myObservable2 = Observable.just("second observer");

    //list as observable
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    Observable myObservable3 = Observable.from(list);

    //subscription
    myObservable1.subscribe(mySubscriber);
    myObservable2.subscribe(mySubscriber);
    myObservable3.subscribe(mySubscriber);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you debug through the code to check if he enters the subscriber? I would also implement the onError of the subscriber so you know if something goes wrong.

Comment: I added a log inside onError but it does nt show any thing..also, when I comment out 1st and 2nd observer, then myObserver3 works finr

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415522/reuse-subscriber

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221802/how-can-i-reuse-a-subscriber-between-two-observables-rxjava

Comment: As I see it a subscriber should not be reused. I find it weird that it works for 2 observables

Comment: Subscribers can't be reused, marked as completed by first completed subscription. Just create separate instances for all three observables and all be ok

Comment: @udalmik i think you ment to say I should create separate insatnce of each subscriber not observer..right?

Comment: yes, I meant separate instances for subscribers