# Why do we need Observer.from()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am learning RxJava in Android. I am following this tutorial here:
http://plavatvornica.com/rxjava-for-beginners/

as shown in the code below,i created an observable that emits the items in a list one by onError

I have a question to deepn my understaning of the usage of RxJava libarary. the questio is, why do I need to use RxJava to gt items from a list one by one? i could
do the same think using a loop!! since RxJava library offers such feature,I believe it should have ensued due to a specific need.

can you please help me to understand it

**code**

```
Subscriber listSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "I am done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNext: " + s);

    }
};

 //list as observable
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    Observable myObservable3 = Observable.from(list);

    myObservable3.subscribe(listSubscriber);
```

Comment: This example is how to use the library, not take advantage of the reactive programming idioms.

Comment: @MarkKeen but how can i make 10 observers to have the same results??AFAIK, each observer must have only one subscriber??isnt it?

Comment: 1 observable with multiple subscribers .. makes total sense to me .. look into hot and cold observables if it doesn't make sense..

Comment: @MarkKeen actually, today i have asked this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322943/observable-from-does-not-work    because when I used one subscriber from several observerables i ..it did not work

Comment: You are getting confused with observables (producers) and observers (consumers)... One producer can have multiple consumers..

Comment: @MarkKeen i think the consumer "observer" is the method inside the observable like call()..right?

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the idea of Reactive Programming: nothing is hopping until you sent a message, i.e. in the real application the data will never be requested until you subscribe to the observer. Your example, particularly, doesn't express this idea. But, if it would be, for example, database fetching, then it would be helpful. Moreover, reactive programming especially nice when async programming, because allows process data by part directly it was received without idle.